# Understanding time complexity for kth minimum in CLRS

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, recursion, divide-and-conquer

In chapter [10.3. Selection in worst - case linear time ($k$th minimum)](http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~csli/graduate/algorithms/book6/chap10.htm) from *Introduction to Algorithms* by Cormen, Leiserson and Rivest, the time complexity expected for step 5 of the algorithm presented in this chapter is said to take $T(n)=7n/10 + 6$ at worst.

From my point of view the time complexity is the one specified above because the number of elements larger than the median of all medians is at least $3n/10-6$, thus the remaining search space is $7n/10 + 6$, where $n$ is the size of input data.

How off am I?

Comment: I am confused by your question. Are you disagreeing or agreeing with the claim? Where/why do you think you're "off"?

Comment: @ryan I agree with the claim and I'm trying to give myself some kind of intuitive reasoning. I'm not entirely sure that my way of seeing this is plausible/ true.

Comment: Note that you are in all likelihood linking to a pirated copy of CLRS. (I doubt that the owner of the website has a license for world-wide distribution of CLRS.) You should instead transcribe the algorithm here so the question can stand on its own.

Comment: Which reasoning does the book give? Have you tried a [precise derivation](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis) as opposed to remaining on the intuitive level?